# How can I create multiple trigger events in Google Sheet for a single sendMailEdit function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, gmail

I am currently trying to write a script that will send an email to different people when different columns are edited.

For example, if column A is edited, an email should be sent to AAA@gmail.com. If column B is edited, an email should be sent to BBB@gmail.com

I've written a script that works when sending an email to one person, but when I try add another trigger event, the script stops working.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function sendMailEdit(e){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("REVIEW");
   if (e.range.columnStart != 8) return;
   const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,20).getValues();
   let sub = rData[0][2];
   let sta = rData[0][3];
   let pos = rData[0][4];
   let dep = rData [0][5];
   let jur = rData [0][6];
   let acc = rData [0][7];
   let rem = rData [0][14];
   let msg = 'A new account access request has been added to ';
       msg+='<a href="'+SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl()+'#gid='+e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()+'">TEST GLOBAL - Account Access</a>';
       msg+='<br>●Submitter: ' + sub;
       msg+='<br>●Email: ' + sta;
       msg+='<br>●Staff Position: ' + pos;
       msg+='<br>●Department: ' + dep;
       msg+='<br>●Jurisdiction: ' + jur;
       msg+='<br>●Account Access: ' + acc;
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "AAA@gmail.com",
     subject: "Global - New Account Access Request",
     htmlBody: msg,
     noReply: true
   });

   if (e.range.columnStart != 13 || e.value != "APPROVED") return;
   let msg2 = 'A new account access request has been added to ';
       msg2+='<a href="'+SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl()+'#gid='+e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()+'">TEST GLOBAL - Account Access</a>';
       msg2+= ' which has been aproved by the Business Operations Team.';
       msg2+='<br>●Submitter: ' + sub;
       msg2+='<br>●Email: ' + sta;
       msg2+='<br>●Staff Position: ' + pos;
       msg2+='<br>●Department: ' + dep;
       msg2+='<br>●Jurisdiction: ' + jur;
       msg2+='<br>●Account Access: ' + acc;
       msg2+='<br>●Remarks: ' + rem;
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "BBB@gmail.com",
     subject: "Global - New Account Access Request",
     htmlBody: msg2,
     noReply: true
   });
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your question and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike in the script I wrote, the trigger "if (e.range.columnStart != 8) return;" should send an email to AAA. Then "if (e.range.columnStart != 13 || e.value != "APPROVED") return;" should send an email to BBB.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The `return` statement will exit your function and not execute any of the code in the lines below it

What you probably want is something like

```js
 if (e.range.columnStart == 8){
  ...
  MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "AAA@gmail.com",
     subject: "Global - New Account Access Request",
     htmlBody: msg,
     noReply: true
   });
 }
else if(e.range.columnStart != 13 || e.value != "APPROVED"){
  ...
  MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "BBB@gmail.com",
     subject: "Global - New Account Access Request",
     htmlBody: msg2,
     noReply: true
   });
  }
}
```

- The combination of [`if` and `else if`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp) means that the script checks first either the first `if` condition is fullfilled.
- If the first condition is fullfilled, the script executes the respective code block (sending en email to AAA)
- If the first condition is not fullfilled, the script jumps to the second conditional statement (`else if`)
- If the second condition is fullfilled, the script executes the respective code block (sending en email to BBB)
- If none of the two conditions is fullfilled, the script does not execute any of the respective code blocks
- If both conditions are fullfilled - the script executes only the first code block, since the `if else` implies the the second code block is only executed ith the first condition is not fullfilled

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your detailed answer makes it really clear. But when I type 'else if' in the script, this error message appears "Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else' line: 23 file"

Comment: Are you sure you closed the `}` bracket of the `if` statement correctly immediately before the `else if` statement? Please mind that the `...` in my answer are for skipping long code parts and make the logic clearer, but of course you need to replace them correctly with your code.

Comment: `function sendMailEdit(e){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("REVIEW");
   if (e.range.columnStart != 13 || e.value != "APPROVED") return;{
   const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,20).getValues();
   ...
   MailApp.sendEmail({
   ...
   });
   }
   
   else if (e.range.columnStart != 8) return;{
   const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,20).getValues();
   ...
   MailApp.sendEmail({
   ...
   });
   }
}`

Comment: Here is what I wrote, do I need to remove `return`? When I removed `return` the code stopped working completely which is why I left it in.

Comment: Yes, you need to either remove `return` or put it at the end of the code block within `{...}`. NEVER between `if(...)` and `{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, so maybe this will be helpful.

I needed to send an email to one person when Column A was marked "complete", to another person when Column B was marked "issue", etc. So at first I duplicated the functions, but App Script will only run one sendMailEdit function.

BUT, I was able to rename the functions (didn't know you could do that), then set up a trigger for each one, i.e. I renamed and modified:

```
function sendMailEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 17 || e.value != "complete") return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 18).getValues();

  let teacher = rData[0][2];
  let studentFirst = rData[0][3];
  let studentLast = rData[0][4];
  let enrolled = rData[0][11];
  let withdrawn = rData[0][13];
  let emailAddress = rData[0][1];
  let notes = rData[0][17];

  let msg = "Hi, " + teacher + ". Your student, " + studentFirst + " " + studentLast + " has been enrolled in " + enrolled + "and/or withdrawn from " + withdrawn + "\n\n " + notes + ".\n\nThis is an auto-generated response, please do not reply to this message."
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "Enrollment and/or Withdrawal Notification", msg)
}
```

to

```
function processIssue(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart != 17 || e.value != "issue") return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, 18).getValues();

  let teacher = rData[0][2];
  let studentFirst = rData[0][3];
  let studentLast = rData[0][4];
  let emailAddress = rData[0][1];
  let notes = rData[0][17];

  let msg = "Hi, " + teacher + ". There is an issue with the enrollment/withdrawal request for " + studentFirst + " " + studentLast + ". Please contact the Enrollment Team at blank@myschool.org.\n\n " + notes + ".\n\nThis is an auto-generated response, please DO NOT REPLY TO THIS MESSAGE."
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "Enrollment and/or Withdrawal Notification", msg)
}
```

Then I created two triggers:
One for sendMailEdit
and another for processIssue

Both functions do basically the same thing, but now you can give each one a trigger of its own to fire "on edit".